# Is recursion a loop

Tags: algorithm

"1. The program will calculate the values using repetitive execution (loops)."

Recursion is repetitive execution but, i do not think it's a loop, do you think if I used recursion it would follow the guideline above?

Comment: Thanks david, wasn't exactly sure where to put this.

Comment: The term "loop" can be used abstractly ( a cycle in the execution path of your program) or concretely (a syntactic construct to guide such a cycle). The question implies the latter usage.

Answer (score 3):

No. In fact, it looks like the assignment is specifically asking for the "opposite" of recursion, [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing).

Answer (score 1):

Loops are fundamentally about *iteration*, which is different to *recursion*. The main difference is that an iteration uses a constant amount of space, whereas recursion uses more space the deeper the recursion goes. For example, here are iterative and recursive procedures to compute the sum of the numbers from 1 to n

```
def sum_iter(n):
  x = 0
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    x += i
  return x

def sum_recursive(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return n + sum_recursive(n-1)
```

If you run these with a very large argument, you will run out of stack space (a "stack overflow") on the recursive version, but the iterative version will work fine.

There is a special kind of recursion called *tail recursion*, which is where the function doesn't have to do anything with the value from a recursive call except pass it to the caller. In this case you don't need to keep track of the stack - you can just jump straight to the top. This is called *tail call optimization*. A tail recursive function to calculate the sum of the integers 1 to n looks like

```
def sum_tailrec(n):
  def helper(s,i):
    if i == 0:
      return s
    else:
      return helper(s+i, i-1)
  return helper(0, n)
```

In this case people often refer to the function `helper` as an  iterative recursion, because (with tail call optimization) it is only using a constant amount of space.

This is all a bit moot, because Python doesn't have tail call optimization, but [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) [languages](http://ocaml.org/) [do](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell).